# "Far slower" versus "Far more slowly"

Tags: adverbs, comparatives

Are both of these statements grammatically correct?  Do they have different connotations?  Or are they interchangeable?

- Alice grew *far slower* than Bob
- Alice grew *far more slowly* than Bob

Comment: I think they are exactly the same.  Both expressions seem a little awkward.  One wants to say "slowlier", but that is not a word.

Comment: But did they eventually reach the same height? Perhaps the sentence should be "Alice grew less than Bob."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Too slow/Too slowly](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/474952/too-slow-too-slowly) // [speak slower or speak slowlier?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78244/speak-slower-or-speak-slowlier)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Speak Slower or Speak Slowlier?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78244/speak-slower-or-speak-slowlier) See also [“More clear” vs “Clearer”: when to use “more” instead of “-er”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/more-clear-vs-clearer-when-to-use-more-instead-of-er)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slow(adverb) = slowly; comparative form "slower."

Slowly = an adverb; comparative form "more slowly".

So, both your sentences seem fine.